# can i burn a programme on pic18f452 using avr isp

Tags: pic, avr, pickit

I'm using pic18f452. It's programmer is quite costly. so, i wanted to know if whether i can burn a programme on pic18f452 using avr isp profeammer or not

If yes then how

Comment: No. AVR ISP can only program AVR MCUs.

Comment: but someone this website asked a similar question and people said yes we can burn pic programmes using  isp programmer.

Comment: but the links they provided are not opening up      http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4389/is-it-possible-to-use-avr-isp-programmer-to-program-a-pic-chip        Turbo J

Comment: You'd probably be best to edit your question to say the exact AVR programmer(s) you have. There is some possibility for a specific programmer someone has written alternative firmware / software that will program that PIC, but probably not likely. If you don't want to spend $50 on a Microchip programmer you can probably find alternatives for about $10 on e-bay.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can't use boat to drive to work on the highway either.

Comment: please elabroate

Comment: @Anmol: You can't use a car to drive across open water either.

Comment: @AnmolNarang: Olin is being funny... In theory 'yes' see the other answers. Why do you want to do this? These devices are different enough that trying this means you would have be expert in pc, avr , pic programming and electronics. What a lot of effort.. why do you wish to do this? It's cheap to buy a programmer as other have said. Or is this a case of...if my only tool is a hammer you can still hammer screws in to wood.

Comment: @Spoon: I wasn't trying to be funny as much as point out how silly and stupid the request was.  He is asking *"How do I drive to work on the highway with this boat?"*.  There is no more reason to expect a AVR programmer to program a PIC than for a boat to drive down the highway.  And before you say this is a newbie that didn't know better, surely which chips his programmer supports is documented.  So this is a dumb question all around, not the least because the answer is to look at the programmer documentation and see if the PIC 18F452 is supported.  Duh.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I understand you completely but I believe the OP did not. Sometimes the 'obvious' is not clear to those new to the subject... I've seen this a good few times... and I have seen a hammer used..esp when it's your only tool at hand